# regex for list of users except the user fetching it?

Tags: javascript, regex, mongoose

Below is the code in which the filter is the query parameter at the endpoint bulk and we use this filter that user has typed in his dashboard, this filter should fetch all the users he filtered through his filter from all users except the user himself but now it fetches all of it(his user including) ???

```
router.get("/bulk",async (req, res) => {
  const filter = req.query.filter || "";

  const users = await User.find({
    $or: [
      {
        firstName: {
          $regex: filter,
        },
      },
      {
        lastName: {
          $regex: filter,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
  

  res.json({
    user: users.map((user) => ({
      username: user.username,
      firstName: user.firstName,
      lastName: user.lastName,
      _id: user._id,
    }))
  });
});
```

, tried to use .filter in .map but doesnt work, other regex failed too

Comment: I edited tags for you, next time **don't forget to tag your language**

Comment: You need to do `users.filter(user => user._id !== currUserId).map((user) => ... )`

Comment: problem is users._id is a mongoose.Types.Object and the currUserId is string so how to do this???

Comment: Maybe `user.username != currUserId`?

Comment: Yuo can also do it in the query, with `$and:` and a condition for not matching the current user. I don't know the Mongoose syntax for it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with regex. Please read wikipedia or similar what a regex actually is...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$and` and `$or` in combination like so:

```js
const users = await User.find({
  $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        {
          firstName: {
            $regex: filter
          }
        },
        {
          lastName: {
            $regex: filter
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      _id: {
        $ne: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(currUserId)
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

This will find all users where the `firstName` or `lastName` matches the `$regex` query based on a case sensitive `filter` but not where the `_id` matches the `currUserId`.

You can use whatever field you want in the `$ne` stage to remove the current user from the returned results.

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C6NdjpXns6_) for a working example.